# raphael pie chart always blue when there is only 1 value (how to set color of a pie with one slice)

Tags: raphael, pie-chart, graphael

I am having an issue with raphael pie charts. The data I am using is dynamic, and in some instances, only 1 value is returned, meaning the whole chart is filled, as it is the ONLY slice. The problem is that when there is only 1 value, it ignores my color designation.

For example: Below is the creation of a raphael pie chart with 2 values, and each slice has the proper color designated in the "colors" section:

```
var r = Raphael("holder");  
r.piechart(160, 136, 120, [100,200],{colors: ["#000","#cecece"]});
```

This works fine, and I get two properly sized slices, one black, and one grey.

However the example below creates one full pie, ALWAYS filled with blue, regardless of my color setting.

```
var r = Raphael("holder");  
r.piechart(160, 136, 120, [100],{colors: ["#000"]});
```

In this situation, I really need that full pie to be black, as it is set in "colors"

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INMO its a bug cause when the pie got only one slice its color is hard coded...

Here is how I solved it (all I did is use the `colors` arg if it exist...)

in [g.pie.js](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/blob/master/g.pie.js) after line 47 add this

```
var my_color =  chartinst.colors[0];
if(opts.colors !== undefined){
    my_color =  opts.colors[0];
}
```

then in the following line (line 48 in the original js file)

```
series.push(paper.circle(cx, cy, r).attr({ fill: chartinst.colors[0]....
```

replace the `chartinst.colors[0]` with `my_color`

that's it

```
   if (len == 1) {
        var my_color =  chartinst.colors[0];
        if(opts.colors !== undefined){
            my_color =  opts.colors[0];
        }
        series.push(paper.circle(cx, cy, r).attr({ fill: my_color,   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out on your own since this question is already a day old...  but you can "trick" Raphael into rendering a black unit by special-casing datasets of one to add an infinitesimal second value.  So, given an array data with your data points...

```
if ( data.length == 1 )
    data.push( 0.000001 );

canvas.piechart(250, 250, 120, data, {colors: ["#000", "#CECECE", "#F88" /*, ... */ ] });
```

The tiny sliver will still be rendered as a single-pixel line in the 180 degree position, but you could probably fudge that by playing with your color palette.

Yes, it's a trick.  I don't believe gRaphael's behavior is buggy so much as poorly implemented (single-element datasets are obviously special cased since they produce a circle instead of a path as they would in all other cases).

Answer (score 0):

Easy way for me without edit g.pie.js

```
var r = Raphael('st_diagram');

r.piechart(140, 140, 137, 100, 0.0001],{

        colors:['#9ae013','#9ae013'],
        strokewidth: 0
    });
```